# как в html таблицу выгрузить данные с бд

Tags: php, html, sql

как в html таблицу выгрузить данные с бд
Сам код таблици

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TinyTable</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tablewrapper">
        <div id="tableheader">
            <div class="search">
                <select id="columns" onchange="sorter.search('query')"></select>
                <input type="text" id="query" onkeyup="sorter.search('query')" />
            </div>
            <span class="details">
                <div>Records <span id="startrecord"></span>-<span id="endrecord"></span> of <span id="totalrecords"></span></div>
                <div><a href="javascript:sorter.reset()">reset</a></div>
            </span>
        </div>






        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="tinytable">

            <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th><h3>позначення НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3> назва НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>чинність НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3> кількість сторінок в НД</h3></th>
                    </tr>


            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                //соединение с базой данных при помощи функции mysql_connect()
  //в аргументах функции укажите имя сервера, логин и пароль. 
                    $db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:55767","postgres","postgres");
  //функция mysql_select_db() выбирает текущую 
  //базу данных с именем "komtet_test"
                    mysql_select_db("schedule" ,$db);
  //функция mysql_query() выполняет запрос на выборку данных 
  //результирующий набор данных хранится в переменной $sql
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links" ,$db);
  //функция mysql_fetch_row() извлекает одну строку из результата 
  //и сохраняет её в массиве $tablerows
                    while ($tablerows = mysql_fetch_row($sql))
  
  //теперь в цикле для каждой полученной строки сделаем вывод 
  //$tablerows[1] соответствует полю "url" 
  //$tablerows[2] соответствует полю "description" 
                    echo <tr><td><a href="/info/tech/$tablerows[1]">$tablerows[1]
        </a></td><td>$tablerows[2]</td></tr> 
                    mysql_close($db)
                ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="tablefooter">
          <div id="tablenav">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/first.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1,true)" />
                    <img src="images/previous.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1)" />
                    <img src="images/next.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(1)" />
                    <img src="images/last.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Last Page" onclick="sorter.move(1,true)" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="pagedropdown"></select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="javascript:sorter.showall()">view all</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tablelocation">
                <div>
                    <select onchange="sorter.size(this.value)">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                    <span>Entries Per Page</span>
                </div>
                <div class="page">Page <span id="currentpage"></span> of <span id="totalpages"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter','table',{
        headclass:'head',
        ascclass:'asc',
        descclass:'desc',
        evenclass:'evenrow',
        oddclass:'oddrow',
        evenselclass:'evenselected',
        oddselclass:'oddselected',
        paginate:true,
        size:10,
        colddid:'columns',
        currentid:'currentpage',
        totalid:'totalpages',
        startingrecid:'startrecord',
        endingrecid:'endrecord',
        totalrecid:'totalrecords',
        hoverid:'selectedrow',
        pageddid:'pagedropdown',
        navid:'tablenav',
        sortcolumn:1,
        sortdir:1,
        sum:[8],
        avg:[6,7,8,9],
        columns:[{index:7, format:'%', decimals:1},{index:8, format:'$', decimals:0}],
        init:true
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Пробовал таким способом

```
<?php
                    //соединение с базой данных при помощи функции mysql_connect()
      //в аргументах функции укажите имя сервера, логин и пароль. 
                        $db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:55767","postgres","postgres");
      //функция mysql_select_db() выбирает текущую 
      //базу данных с именем "komtet_test"
                        mysql_select_db("schedule" ,$db);
      //функция mysql_query() выполняет запрос на выборку данных 
      //результирующий набор данных хранится в переменной $sql
                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links" ,$db);
      //функция mysql_fetch_row() извлекает одну строку из результата 
      //и сохраняет её в массиве $tablerows
                        while ($tablerows = mysql_fetch_row($sql))
      
      //теперь в цикле для каждой полученной строки сделаем вывод 
      //$tablerows[1] соответствует полю "url" 
      //$tablerows[2] соответствует полю "description" 
                        echo <tr><td><a href="/info/tech/$tablerows[1]">$tablerows[1]
            </a></td><td>$tablerows[2]</td></tr> 
                        mysql_close($db)
                    ?>
```

Но в итоге ничего

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переформулировал вопрос

Comment: Используйте mysqli и не используйте индексы. Если Вы когда нибудь измените таблицу в бд, например, добавите столбец, то Ваш скрипт - сдохнет т.к. индексы сдвинутся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте **mysqli** и **не используйте** **индексы**. Если Вы когда нибудь измените таблицу в бд, например, добавите столбец, то Ваш скрипт - сдохнет т.к. индексы сдвинутся.

Попробуйте таким образом (поменяйте только данные на свои).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TinyTable</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tablewrapper">
        <div id="tableheader">
            <div class="search">
                <select id="columns" onchange="sorter.search('query')"></select>
                <input type="text" id="query" onkeyup="sorter.search('query')" />
            </div>
            <span class="details">
                <div>Records <span id="startrecord"></span>-<span id="endrecord"></span> of <span id="totalrecords"></span></div>
                <div><a href="javascript:sorter.reset()">reset</a></div>
            </span>
        </div>






        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="tinytable">

            <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th><h3>позначення НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>назва НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>чинність НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3> кількість сторінок в НД</h3></th>
                    </tr>


            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $db = new mysqli("localhost","ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ ","ПАРОЛЬ","ИМЯ БД");
                    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM links");
                    $_r = $sql->num_rows;
                    if ($_r > 0)
                    {
                        while ($tablerows = $sql->fetch_array())
                        {
                            echo '
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[1].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[2].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>Lorem ip..</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>2 Lorem ip..</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            
                            
                            ';
                            
                            
                        }                       
                        
                    }else{
                        echo '<tr><td colspan=4 style="text-align: center;">Ничего нет</td></tr>';
                    }

                ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="tablefooter">
          <div id="tablenav">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/first.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1,true)" />
                    <img src="images/previous.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1)" />
                    <img src="images/next.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(1)" />
                    <img src="images/last.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Last Page" onclick="sorter.move(1,true)" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="pagedropdown"></select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="javascript:sorter.showall()">view all</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tablelocation">
                <div>
                    <select onchange="sorter.size(this.value)">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                    <span>Entries Per Page</span>
                </div>
                <div class="page">Page <span id="currentpage"></span> of <span id="totalpages"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter','table',{
        headclass:'head',
        ascclass:'asc',
        descclass:'desc',
        evenclass:'evenrow',
        oddclass:'oddrow',
        evenselclass:'evenselected',
        oddselclass:'oddselected',
        paginate:true,
        size:10,
        colddid:'columns',
        currentid:'currentpage',
        totalid:'totalpages',
        startingrecid:'startrecord',
        endingrecid:'endrecord',
        totalrecid:'totalrecords',
        hoverid:'selectedrow',
        pageddid:'pagedropdown',
        navid:'tablenav',
        sortcolumn:1,
        sortdir:1,
        sum:[8],
        avg:[6,7,8,9],
        columns:[{index:7, format:'%', decimals:1},{index:8, format:'$', decimals:0}],
        init:true
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас проблема с выводом в цикле. Вставте этот код на место вашего цикла:

```
while ($tablerows = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
  $row = <<<TEXT
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/info/tech/$tablerows[1]">$tablerows[1]</a></td>
      <td>$tablerows[2]</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>      
    </tr>
  TEXT;
        
  echo $row;
}
mysql_close($db)
```

Не забудьте вынести mysql_close($db) за пределы цикла